# How Do I Access Magento 2 Theme Files on a Virtual Box Server

Tags: apache, virtualbox, magento2

I am new to Magento development and I am trying to learn how themes work. I am not sure how to access the theme files that are within the Virtual Box Magento server that I built.

I have looked around in phpMyAdmin but I am new to that as well so I am not sure if it is even there.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure many people know this but from a newbie to Magento development this is what I did:

To download themes which is what I wanted to do and test themes that I build you can just clone them into the folder within the magento frontend folder / and from there keep pulling as you make updates on your main computer.